# How to better express the idea of "written communication"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, adjectives, analogy

As compared to "verbal communication" or "visual communication", I was wondering if there was a synonym for "written communication"  that is semantically similar to the first two. What throws me off is that written is both a verb and an adjective, while verbal and visual are singularly adjectives. Is this a distinction I should even worry about?

Comment: It is always admirable to worry about distinction — and then dismiss the worry if it is groundless! I observe, however, that both *written* and *oral* (or *aural*) communications are *verbal* — expressed in words — and that *written* differs from the others *grammatically* or *structurally* rather than *semantically*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry about what part of speech these three words are for two reasons:

> First, *verbal* is a [noun](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/verbal) as well as an adjective;
>
> Second, it doesn't matter what part of speech they are but how they are used.

If you have an example sentence that might confuse a reader or listener, please provide, though.

Comment: I'm not sure that it would ever be confusing, I was just looking for a word that fit the same grammatical style as the other two.

Answer (score 0):

I think *Textual communication* is the officially accepted equivalent.

Comment: What office would that be?